# Linkedhashmap inside ArrayList of Objects, get data

Tags: java, json

EDIT: 
Im parsing a JSON. The JSON have this form

```
  {
     "responseObject": {
            "slots_0": [
                            { //SlotItem (date, string, int, boolean },
                            { //SlotItem } 
              ],               
           "slots_1": [
                            { //SlotItem (date, string, int, boolean },
                            { //SlotItem } 
                            { //SlotItem } 
              ]
     }, 
    "messages" : "Hi Stackoverflow"
}
```

I can't parse my response with slot_0, slot_1 because I can have more  that only two actually I can have slot_n, responseObject will be an array of arrays of SlotItems, if Im not wrong.

I make this parsing first (Because I only need responseObject)

`Hashmap <String, String> response = (Hashmap<String, String>) response.get("responseObject")`

So after that I try to make an `ArrayList<SlotItem []>`

Prior my edit I was trying this way:

I want to have an ArrayList of an array of Objects

```
ArrayList <SlotItem []> slotsinfo
```

Inside the ArrayList I have this structure:
[image]

I want to get a simple ArrayList, not a LinkedHashMap.
Because I want to retrieve the information in this way

```
String storeId = slotsinfo.get(index).getStoreId();
```

Inside SlotItem I have getters and setters.

I try to retrieve the data getting inside the list using get(index), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>`, not a `ArrayList<SlotItem[]>`

> I want to get a simple ArrayList, not a LinkedHashMap. Because i want
>   to retriever the information in this way
>
> ```
> String storeId = slotsinfo.get(index).getStoreId();
> ```

Okay, then you need to fix however you are getting that data to have a `ArrayList<SlotItem>`.

As it currently stands, you should be able to do

```
result.get(index).get("storeId");
```

EDIT

Try to get your JSON like this, making `responseObject` an array of arrays

```
{
     "responseObject": [
              [
                   { //SlotItem (date, string, int, boolean },
                   { //SlotItem } 
              ],               
              [
                   { //SlotItem (date, string, int, boolean },
                   { //SlotItem } 
                   { //SlotItem } 
              ]
     ], 
    "messages" : "Hi Stackoverflow"
}
```

Comment: I update my post, maybe you can help me with this. I can't do The part of get("storeId"). Thank you So much.

Comment: You really should reformat your JSON, if at all possible. Having keys of x0, x1,..., xn means you need an array. You do not show an array of arrays, you show a dictionary of key-values, where all values are arrays. Your current format requires you to do `responseObject.get("slot_0").get(index).get("storeId")`. If you did have an array of arrays, you could loop over all arrays of `responseObject` in order. Currently, you'd have to loop over the `keySet` of the response object

Comment: Thats actually the problem, because I can't reformat the JSON, (Is an awful json that not even the way it should be) I will try to check the results of the loop, Thank you so much